# role management while implementing jwt in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am working on a learning project where I have three type of users right now:

1. Student
2. Tutor
3. Admin

the client side of the project is based in angular and server side on spring boot.

Now i am starting to intergrate **jwt security** in my server side.

i have to create **role based authorisation** on server side

the problem is that i have two tables in my database i.e. tutor_profile and student_profile

and not a single table with all the users and their roles.

my solution to it was that i will send role type in payload along with email and password when generating token..but still seems unclear.

i am open to solution regarding the problem

Answer (score 0):

First of all whether you should use same table or different table for tutor and student, should be decided on requirement and ui-design.

Are there a separate login options for toutor and student. If yes, then, you can have two different user tables. Based on the login type you can load the data from respective table and send the token back.

If it is a same login for both toutor and student, then it is better to have a same user table and have one more user_role like `ROLE_BOTH`(You can give any other name of your choice) along with `ROLE_STUDENT`, `ROLE_TOUTOR` and `ROLE_ADMIN`.

Hope you will be storing a set of `Permissions` or `Granted_Authorities` for each user role and save them in a separate table. For `ROLE_BOTH` you have to club the Permissions or Granted_Authorities of `ROLE_STUDENT` and `ROLE_TOUTOR`.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: i have two different login tables..so does it mean that i have to create two different authenticate endpoints for both student and admin that will generate jwts..and now whenever i want to use an api that is specific(suppose tutor)..then how it will detect that it is a tutor just from jwt..remember even if i have two different login tables .i can still have same emails..means a tutor can be student

Comment: It is better to have two endpoints. toutorLogin and studentLogin. But if you want implement in single API also you can pass a variable `loginAs' either toutor or student and based on that in backend you can query respective table. That is up to you. Both way is possible.

Comment: To answer your second question, While generating JWT, you can add the `role` in it as a claim. Later when you decrypt the token you can always get a role.

Comment: But my question to you, out of curiosity, If a toutor can also be student then he should be able to toutor for his students and at the same time student to some other touter in the same login. How can you handle that if there are two login tables?

Comment: both of the users (student and tutor) will get their own session even with the same email id.. i don't think its a good practice.